# IEC 61000-4-5 1000V Surge protection for high-side MOSFET output

Tags: digital-logic, switches, tvs

I have following schematic, which must withstand 1000V Surge, applied on output OUT according to IEC61000-4-5. 
As it is signal output the series resistance of IEC Generator is 42 Ohm and I want to use SMAJ26A TVS to clamp this voltage to about 45V, which should be OK. The problem is that my High-side Switch has a parasitic diode, which allows reverse current to flow into Capacitor C1. The rating of this diode seems to be relatively low - just 0.2A, so most likely it's going to be damaged. Or not?
How to resolve this problem? One solution would be to use external reverse diode of appropriate rating together with some current-limiting resistor. But then TVS seems to be redundant. How this is resolved typically?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyXH3i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: AS this spec referes to AC line testing, will this DC line be exposed like AC lines to lightning? Or is this  an automotive spec for trucks??

Comment: You could put a diode from the output to the positive pole of the battery. Depending on the type of battery, and the expected nature of the impulse, this may or may not give you an acceptable protection.

Comment: Tony, IEC 61000-4-5 is also applied to signal ports if they cross system boundaries, or connection lines are long. In this case this is typical industrial environment.